# DateTimeParseException thrown for unknown reason

Tags: java, scala, time

Here is the full error line:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseexception: Text '01-Jan-2020' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Here is the code I am using that throws the error:

```
val DATETIME_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-yyyy").withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"))
val parsedTime = DATETIME_FORMAT.parse(input)
```

the `input` variable is '01-Jan-2020' as seen in the error line.
I have looked at many similar questions to this one but it's not the expected solution. Can anybody enlighten me on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Check your pattern "d-MMM-yyyy" -> you should use "dd-MMM-yyyy"

Comment: I have tested that format and I still run into the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to set Locale as second parameter ofPattern method, look below (working code in java)

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

var parsedTime = dateTimeFormatter.parse("01-Jan-2020");
```

Comment: Tried this exactly as you typed and it still throws the same error

Comment: Can you show me the error from my solution?

Comment: Same as above:
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01-Jan-2020' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: This works for me, I get `{},ISO,UTC resolved to 2020-01-01`. @C.Mag I bet you have got some non-printing character at the front of your string.